# Combine, Zip or how to include or squeeze in a stream into a stream

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am not sure what exactly to use but lately, I have had a lot of trouble with RxJava when I am working with code that has streams for everything.

In my case, let say I have to get an instance of an object, that I need for some processing from a stream that is available, let's call this NeededInstance and so I have access to Observable of NeededInstance.

Next, what I am doing is I have a **Single** of a **List** of **SomeObject** and what I do is I need to iterate over all items and update them.

**I do this in the following way:**

```
.map(/*in this map the Single<List<SomeObject>> is created*/)
.flatMap(Single<List<SomeObject>> -> updateWithData(Single<List<SomeObject>>);
```

**this is how I wanted my updateWithData function to look like:**

```
private Single<List<SomeObject>> updateWithData(List<SomeObject> list) {
return 
Observable.just(list)
.flatMapIterable(listItem -> listItem)
.flatMapSingle(listItem -> updateListItem(listItem))
.toList();
}
```

I do the above code so that I can transform a chain from handling a single list to an observable of items that I update and return to a list again. Below is the updateListItem function, where trouble comes when I try to get something from that other stream I mention in the beginning:

```
updateListItem(ListItem listItem) {
return
Observable<NeededInstance>.map(Optional::get)
.flatMapSingle(neededInstance -> workWithListItemAndNeededInstace(listItem, neededInstance))
.map(integer -> {
// do something with integer soming from the above method and with a listItem passed into this function
}
return Single.just(updatedListItem)
}
```

so, to be sure, workWithListItemAndNeededInstance can't update the listItem, I just get an Integer object there and with that, I have to do my own updating of listItem. Then I am trying to either return a Single of a listItem or listItem itself and somehow make it available for a .toList() so that in the end I still have a **Single** of a **List** of **ListItem** in the stream.

I am trying with combine but can't really make it work and I find RxJava a bit weird when I have streams that I need to just "drop in" and leave something that I can use for processing.

Any clarification is welcome.

Comment: According to my understanding on the question you mentioned here, Lets say you have neededInstance as a string called test, You have a list of string object ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), Now what you want here is append neededInstance to each item in list and get it as a list back.
So output would be like List of (test1, test2, test3, test4, test5); Is it correct?

Comment: @arungiri_10 yes, with regard that this "test" string that is appended is not always the same and is coming from a Single<String>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//You have a list of string object
List<String> intList = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(intList, "1", "2", "3", "4", "5");

//Now what you want here is append neededInstance to each item in list and get it as a list.
//So output would be like List of (test1, test2, test3, test4, test5);

Observable
    //iterate through the list of items and pass one by one to below stream
    .fromIterable(intList)
    //Each item from the list is passed down to workWithListItemAndNeededInstace
    .flatMap(item -> workWithListItemAndNeededInstace(item))
    .toList()
    .subscribe();

/*
This method will combine item from list with the neededInstance and return a stream of combined data
*/
private Observable<String> workWithListItemAndNeededInstace(String item) {
    return neededInstance().map(instance -> instance + item);
}

/*
This will be your stream from which you get needed stream
 */
private Observable<String> neededInstance() {
    return Observable.just("Need instance");
}
```

Hope this solution gives you a rough idea on what you would want to achieve. Let me know if I missed anything, so that I can update this answer.

Comment: Yes, I finally found also where I was wrong, I was always trying to return a single when I should have been returning an Observable! Thank you!